# Question about UISegmentedControl and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I got a problem.  I try to create a project with Navigation-based Application.
When I press rightBarButtonItem  push to next view.
And that view got a UISegmentedControl right on UINavigationBar.
[image]

I use a IBAction when  press Button A:

```
-(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

when first view show up, I press Button A it will go back to main view.
If I press number 2 on UISegmentedControl , it become to another View,
and still the same method(-(IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender).
But when I press Button B , it wont go back to main view..
[image]

as follow is my method about UISegmentedControl:

```
-(void)showSegmentedView:(id)sender{
AView *aView = [[AView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AView" bundle:nil];
BView *bView = [[BView alloc] initWithNibName:@"BView" bundle:nil];

if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {
    [[seg_view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [seg_view addSubview:aView.view];
} 
else if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex ==1){
    [[seg_view subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    [seg_view addSubview:bView.view];
}
```

}

Does anything wrong??
Thank in advance.

Mini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume seg_view's viewController has been pushed onto the navigationController's stack, self.navigationController on seg_view-Controller then returns your navigationController. However, as when add subviews to it from other viewControllers AView/BView, those UIViewControllers have no connection to seg_view's Controller or the navigationController itself. That means self.navigationController inside the new AView/BView is nil! Depending on your implementation, either backButtonPressed doesn't get called or popViewController in AView or BView does nothing since they don't have a navigationController. I suggest your either don't use other viewControllers (put the 2 views in the same nib as seg_view and interchange them) or push them on the navigationController's stack.